# What are the reasons behind Oracle password restrictions?

Tags: password-policy, oracle

Oracle presents a fairly restrictive password policy:

> Passwords can be from 1 to 30 characters.
>
> The first character in an Oracle password must be a letter.
>
> Only letters, numbers, and the symbols “#”, “_” and “$” are acceptable
>   in a password.

These kind of restrictions pass through to web applications sometimes - either because the system is Oracle backed, or a web developer has copied the rules. For example, the Virgin Media login:[image: Virgin Media password policy].

With best practices dictating salting + hashing, hence no restriction on length or characters, why does Oracle do this? Are there technical reasons, or is it simply a legacy choice?

Comment: The restrictions could be because monkeys don't like water. (I'm in a hurry but I'm sure someone will post the link.)

Comment: I know the story, will google it and link when at desk.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that other character might confuse Oracle parser.
You use SQL change the password:

```
alter user xxx identified by pass;
```

There are NO quotes around the password. So I would say it is for legacy reasons.
Oracle has same restrictions also for identifier/table/column names.

PS: password strength (entropy) is not primary determined by possible chars, but by it's length. In case of the password it's the length what matters.

Comment: Isn't password entropy H = L*logN/log2?

Comment: see this xkcd comic strip: http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/936:_Password_Strength

Comment: I don't agree that the strip supports the notion that password strength is more impacted by length than character set. It supports that a longer password that is memorable is better than a shorter one that isn't. Character set has more of an impact on entropy, and for brute forcing that is important.